# remove autoplay from video on click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have used the following code to add autplay to iframe video onclick.

Html:

```
<span id="stoprotate"></span><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJ2X4dFhAC0?wmode=transparent"  frameborder="0" class="slide" allowtransparency="true" id="video" wmode="opaque"></iframe>
```

script:

```
$(document).on('click','#video',function(e){ 

$(".roundabout-in-focus #video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  $(this).unbind("click");

})

<a href="#">Stop auto play</a>
```

I need to `remove autoplay` on click the stopautoplay link. How to do that?

Comment: so you want to remove the &autoplay=1 from the src when Stop auto played is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Change my answer:P Try to use a global variable to save the url and then reuse it when you click the

```
var gurl;
$(document).on('click','#video',function(e){
    gurl =  $(".roundabout-in-focus #video")[0].src;
    $(".roundabout-in-focus #video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

I wrote a sample:

 http://ohcool.org/sof/13641740.html